# Wordpress php code encoding?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpml

I downloaded wordpress theme , that i like very much and i found problem:D I'm newbie so please dont judge))) I need my site on georgian language , we have own letters like სიტყვა სახელი რამე ტექსტი ,etc.. I filled up all information on my language from wordpress panel, but there is some text what I can't change from wordpress panel. I opened code and found this texts and when I tried to change on my language like I change "My account" on "ჩემი პროფილი"(georgian language) , it looks like "???? ??????" on website. I have no idea what is wrong cause i did it before and I had no problems. Maybe someone can answer on this question, I will be happy if this problem will be solved ^^

```
    <script>
    window.recipeId = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>;
    window.addToFavoritesText = '<i class="ico i-favourites"></i><span><?php _e('***Add to favorites***', 'socialchef') ?></span>';
    window.removeFromFavoritesText = '<i class="ico i-favourites"></i><span><?php _e('Remove from favorites', 'socialchef') ?></span>';
</script>
```

This "add to favourites" I'm trying to change..

Answer (score 0):

I'll change this to a comment when I get 50 rep, sorry.

It's hard to tell what's going on without more information. Are you using a translation plugin to change the English phrases in your WordPress install to Georgian? Or are you trying to hardcode changes in the PHP files? If you're doing that second thing, the best advice I can give you is *don't.*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to stem around character encoding. Getting this right can be a bit tricky in PHP. The [PHP docs](https://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.details) detailing strings should point you in the right direction. Without more information about your setup its hard to know exactly what is causing your issue but from the linked php docs the main take away would be:

> strings will be encoded in whatever fashion it is encoded in the script file. Thus, if the script is written in ISO-8859-1, the string will be encoded in ISO-8859-1 and so on.

What you'd want, is to make sure that your scripts are being encoded in UTF-8.

The other possible issue is if the text you use is being saved to a database and that database is not set to encode its data in UTF-8. I don't know much about the wordpress database but a quick google search turned up [This wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) on how to update your databases's character encoding.

There are other possible issues however I would flag these as the big ones.

Hope this helps!